# Attach a XSL stylesheet to the XML output of a XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm transforming an XML-document into a new restructured XML-document, by attaching a XSLT stylesheet to it. The new XML file is then going to be transformed by a second XSLT.

Is there a way I could make the first XSLT attach the second XSLT to the output?

The output now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <children> 
    ....
```

I want it to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trans.xslt"?>
<root>
  <children> 
     ....
```

Sorry for a somewhat confusing post. But the question is - how do I tell a XSLT stylesheet to add a stylesheet-tag to the output document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use processing-instruction in your template:

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="trans.xslt"</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

Comment: I tried that, but <xsl:processing-instruction> is not allowed as a child element of <xsl:stylesheet>, so it won't run.

Comment: As i've mentioned.. you should use it in your template

Comment: Thank you! It's all a bit blurry for me these things!